# Why Year part of date in update query statement updating wrong year when year is >= 2050

Tags: sql, oracle, date, 2-digit-year

I am trying to insert/update `DATE_OF_RETIREMENT` column, but when the year is >=2050, it takes as 1950.

Example:

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEE
SET STATUS             = '4',
    ISACTIVE           = 1,
    DATE_OF_RETIREMENT = '30-APR-49'
WHERE ID = 2001;
```

Here `DATE_OF_RETIREMENT` is updated with `30 APR 2049`.

But in following case:

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEE
SET STATUS             = '4',
    ISACTIVE           = 1,
    DATE_OF_RETIREMENT = '30-APR-52'
WHERE ID = 2001;
```

Here `DATE_OF_RETIREMENT` with updated with `30 APR 1952`.

Can anyone tell me the reason why this is happening?

Comment: Any reason you don't use four digit years to avoid this problem once and for all? With two digit years obviously *some* dates are inevitably going to end up wrong no matter what window is used. If it's not dates after 2050 it'll be dates after 2060, and if it's not those than eventually the 2100s will end up wrong. The database must make a decision as to what century is meant if only 2 digits are present, and it won't decide correctly for all cases.

Comment: When you don't specify a format or a date language, the database has to fall back on defaults. It looks like your `nls_date_format` is `'DD-MON-RR'` and your `nls_date_language` is English. How should it know what century you mean by `52`?

Comment: Thanks @Jeroen ! Actually it's a legacy system which was working fine up to now but some such issues is raised few days earlier. Now I have take complete 4-digits of years in *date_of_retirement*

Answer (score 3):

Use 4 digits for years; I hope you aren't trying to save some disk space, are you? Y2K is 20 years behind us.

See the difference between `RR` and `YY` format mask for years. Depending on whether it (year) is before or after the 50th year in the century, you'll get a different result.

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> select to_date('30-04-49', 'dd.mm-rr') val1_rr,
  2         to_date('30-04-49', 'dd.mm-yy') val2_yy,
  3         --
  4         to_date('30-04-52', 'dd.mm-rr') val3_rr,
  5         to_date('30-04-52', 'dd.mm-yy') val4_yy
  6  from dual;

VAL1_RR    VAL2_YY    VAL3_RR    VAL4_YY
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
30.04.2049 30.04.2049 30.04.1952 30.04.2052

SQL>
```

Comment: In fairness, the admonition should be addressed to Oracle first. The default date format model, right out of the box, even if I install the database today, is `dd-MON-rr`. Can't fault beginners for assuming that what's good for the default provided by Oracle itself is also good for the user.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, @mathguy. As usual, I enjoy reading them, as well as your answers.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because Oracle has a [built-in century cutoff date,](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E41183_01/DR/Century_Dates.html) and the default is 50. Anything less than or equal to the cut-off year is considered to fall in the current century.